# Error in entering Date in My SQL

Tags: mysql, date

I was trying to enter date into MySQL and was trying to figure out the right syntax through trial and error. In one such command, MySQL accepted the value, however when I displayed the values it showed all zeroes.
[image]
can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Don't forget to use apostrophe for the date value, refer to this:
https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/databases/mysql/insert-date/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must ensure that the value passed to mysql is in year-month-day sequence ("YYYY-MM-DD")

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2016-03-02');
```

***note***:- please use another keyword instead inbuilt keyword.***date*** is inbuilt mysql keyword.
[Read here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: why then does My SQL accept the data in the first place? and why are there only zeroes?

Comment: cause mysql accept ("YYYY-MM-DD") sequence...if you enter for example "20-02-2010" then it convert in zero format cause ("DD-MM-YYYY") not allow in date data type

Answer (score 2):

If you are not passing Date in default format then you need to intimate system that I am passing this string as date by mentioning format of date as describe below.

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES STR_TO_DATE('03-12-2016','%d-%m-%Y');
```

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and also check your date format(data type) set in the database

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2-03-2016')
```

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error? This isn't some uncharted scientific territory where you need to strap on some goggles and use a bunsen burner. There's a [whole chapter in the manual devoted to it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

Dates in MySQL should be in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, that is `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in 24-hour notation.

Please, before wasting tons of your time on pointless experimentation:

## READ THE MANUAL